# How to set width with dynamic table column value in Laravel blade

Tags: html, laravel, progress-bar, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I want to set the width of progress bar with values from database table column called "SHAP_abs". How I can set the width dynamically for each row.
Here is my Blade file:

```
<tr>
              <td class="col-md-4">
                {{ $row }}
              </td>
              @foreach($Correlations_list as $corr)
                @if($corr->Variable == $row )
                  <td class="col-md-4">
                   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ $corr->SHAP_abs }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{ $corr->SHAP_abs*100 }}">
                   </div>   
                  </td>
                @endif
              @endforeach
          </tr>
          @endif
      @endforeach
```

Comment: `SHAP_abs` is a number? 0...100? 0...1?

Comment: Yes..0.54,0.43,0.31....similar kind of values and datatype is varchar(255)

Comment: @JuanEizmendi It's 0...1

Answer (score 0):

Update the attr in the div to match 0...1 values

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: {{ round($corr->SHAP_abs*100) }}%;" aria-valuenow="{{ round($corr->SHAP_abs*100) }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks...I tried the above attr but it not working..returns nothing on view

Comment: Yes...and bar is also not shown, only blank rows

Comment: are the rows passing `@if`?

Comment: Yes..I am getting all the values in first column but column in which bar should appear it's blank

Comment: @if is getting values...if I try set any static value it works fine..even if I am trying to use different progress bar with less than greater than condition its working but I need exact values for each row in progress bar

Comment: I understand that but maybe there is not any `$corr->Variable` matching `$row`, is the `<td>` of the second column showing?

Comment: Yes it shows..if I pass only $corr->SHAP_abs in <td> I get the values...